# Added keys missing from HttpContext.Session (concurrency)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, devextreme

I am using **.NET Core 3.1**. I am wondering if `HttpContext.Session.SetString(...)` is **thread-safe**? For example, client makes two requests to the same controller action (`Test`) at the same time. Controller adds a string to the session (see example below). Will there be two, one or zero keys in the session at the end (ex. when I refresh the page)?

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "test");
    return Ok();
}
```

I am saving some values to session when using **DevExtreme FileUploader**. When I upload multiple files at once, component makes multiple requests at the same time and at the end, there are usually **some keys missing from the session**. I think there is some race condition going on.

**ADDED: CLIENT CODE**

I noticed that session keys are missing only if I use `method: 'POST'` (there is only 1 key). If I use `method: 'GET'`, there are 3 keys (correct).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var method = 'GET'; // works (3 keys)
    //var method = 'POST'; // doesn't work (1 key)

    $('#fire').on('click', function () {
        $.when(
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Session/Test',
                method: method,
                success: function(){
                    console.log('response', 1);
                }
            }),

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Session/Test',
                method: method,
                success: function(){
                    console.log('response', 2);
                }
            }),

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Session/Test',
                method: method,
                success: function(){
                    console.log('response', 3);
                }
            })
        ).then(function () {
            alert('Done');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume you use the default session implementation offered by ASP.Net Core.

**In terms of `HttpContext.Session`:**

`HttpContext.Session` returns an instance of `DistributedSession`, which internally uses a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValaue>`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Session/src/DistributedSession.cs#L72). Dictionary is not thread safe, so if you access `Session` from multiple threads (e.g. `Task.Run`), it can cause unexpected results.

**In terms of Session for different requests:**

In ASP.Net Core, `Session` comes from `ISessionStore`, which has a [transient lifetime](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Session/src/SessionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L28). Meaning, **`Session` object is not shared by requests**. So if you have concurrent requests, each of which will have its own `Session` object.

**In terms of race condition:**

The default implementation of session reads/writes session state from/to `.AspNetCore.Session` cookie. This *may* cause race conditions.

Because `Session` is per client, so you might have race conditions [when you have concurrent requests from the same client touching same bits and pieces in the same cookie / session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-options). The race condition however is not because of `Session` on the server side. It is actually caused by cookie management at client side.

> Session state is non-locking. If two requests simultaneously attempt to modify the contents of a session, the last request overrides the first.

Consider this example:

Say you have a controller action which sets `Session` with provided `value`, and another controller action retrieves the value from `Session` and returns it in body:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("create")]
public IActionResult CreateSession([FromQuery]string value)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("key", value);
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("get")]
public IActionResult ReturnSession([FromQuery] string expected)
{
    var actual = HttpContext.Session.GetString("key");
    return Ok(new { actual, expected });
}
```

If you test these actions with an `HttpClient`:

```
async Task TestSession(HttpClient client, string str)
{
    await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:5001/session/create?value={str}");
    var r = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:5001/session/get?expected={str}");
    var session = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(session);
}

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    await TestSession(client, "abc");
}
```

The output should look like:

```
{"actual":"abc","expected":"abc"}
```

Problem raises when you have concurrent requests from the same client:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var str = i.ToString();
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => TestSession(client, str)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The output looks like:

```
{"actual":"2","expected":"1"}
{"actual":"3","expected":"6"}
{"actual":"4","expected":"5"}
{"actual":"4","expected":"3"}
{"actual":"4","expected":"2"}
{"actual":"8","expected":"4"}
{"actual":"7","expected":"8"}
{"actual":"7","expected":"7"}
{"actual":"9","expected":"0"}
{"actual":"9","expected":"9"}
```

In the above case, session state was changed by *request 3*, between *create* and *get* of *request 6*, meaning it is likely *request 6* cannot see its session state correctly.

To avoid this issue, you could use different `HttpClient` for each batch.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by “If some keys are missing, make sure you include correct cookie once session is updated.”? How do I ensure that correct cookie is included?

Comment: @Mark Session designed to be per client. If you fire multiple requests from the **same** client, they may share the same cookie container, therefore share the same session state. I am not sure how do you mean by *some keys missing from session* in question. But, it is likely that say if you have two requests from same client both triggering the server to update same field in session, you can only have 1 request wins. And for another request, the session is lost / overridden.

Comment: I declared `private static int count = 0;` in the controller and increased its value each time I added something to the session (NOTE: keys added were definitely different - I used GUID). Then, I sent 3 concurrent requests. When I refreshed the page, the value of `count` was 3. However, there was only 1 key in the session. What can be causing this?

Comment: I updated my original question with JS code. I found an interesting difference between `POST` and `GET`. Please take a look at it.

Comment: `GET` does not always work for me. I fired 3 get calls, on the server side, each of which has no keys in `Session` initially. Then the server executes the requests and sets session keys. Now I fire another 3 get calls. I see only 1 key in `Session` on each request. `Post` behaves the same.

Comment: What should I do to have all 3 keys in session at the end?

Comment: If you use `Session`, you have to send request one by one. Read [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-options) *Session state is non-locking. If two requests simultaneously attempt to modify the contents of a session, the last request overrides the first.* Or, you could consider other mechanisms such as [caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#distributed-memory-cache)

Answer (score 0):

No, dotnet collections are not thread safe, and neither is session.
If you are sharing the same session over more than one thread you should treat it as readonly

Comment: Can you provide any reference where I can verify this information?